# X11 error while running heatmap R code

Tags: r, fonts, x11, heatmap

When I run the command:

```
R-2.14.0/bin/R --slave -f heatmap.R
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in axis(1, 1L:nc, labels = labCol, las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0,  :
  X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 9 could not be loaded
Calls: heatmap -> axis
In addition: There were 19 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted
```

Here is the code contained in heatmap.R:

```
require(graphics); require(grDevices)
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
rc <- rainbow(nrow(x), start=0, end=.3)
cc <- rainbow(ncol(x), start=0, end=.3)
png("heatmap.png", height=1500, width=1500)
heatmap(x, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column",
RowSideColors = rc, ColSideColors = cc, margins=c(5,10),
xlab = "specification variables", ylab= "Car Models")
dev.off()
```

How to aviod the X11 error? What configurations needs to be changed?

Comment: Works fine for me, what does warnings() tell you?

Comment: Have you tried it in an interactive R session? Doing so will allow you to investigate in more detail. Also, what operating system are you running this on?

Comment: What does running `capabilities()` in R show you?

Comment: I am running it on putty on a win 7 32-bit with Xming server and X11 forwarding enabled.    `> capabilities()
    jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets
    TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
  libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE`

Comment: Is this http://showmanlkz.blogspot.com/2011/01/x11-xming-confusion-which-x-server-is.html and in particular this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/Xming-fonts/ any use?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the bug by reinstall newly R-base

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error:

```
Error in mtext(plotHeader, cex = 1.6, line = 0.5) :
X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 19 could
Execution halted
```

fixed by changing `"cex=1"` for size parameter

try to introduce and choose suitable `cex` parameter in your plot